# Removing duplicate rows but retaining unique copy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I got a SQL table of the form:-

```
Name     Age
Kim       5
Tom       8
Jim       12
Kim       5
David     21
Jim       12
```

In the above scenario, Kim and Jim are duplicated and they exist twice.

If I have a large table of the above form, with about 60000 entries, how do I write a sql query to delete only the duplicates but still retain the unique ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `Common Table Expression` and a `Window Function`, you can easily delete duplicate records.

```
WITH dups
AS
(
    SELECT  Name, Age,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Age ORDER BY Age DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
DELETE FROM dups
WHERE   rn > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a7d4/1)
- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: hey JW, what is dups as per your query? just a small confusion

Comment: it's the name of the [**CTE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: hey JW, one last doubt..suppose i want to delet row number 5, how do i design d qeury??? something like, Delete from tablename where rownumber=5;

Comment: do you mean fifth row including the duplicates?

Comment: no no JW....just a general query...if i just want to delete fifth row of a table, what is a normal sql query???

Comment: do you have an auto increment column? because it's hard to know the row number of the record.

Comment: i know d row number of the record...so i just want a direct query to delete that particular row...it is ok if d row remains empty after d delete operation...

Comment: oh ok, if you know the row number then you can simply delete it directly `Delete from tablename where rownumber=5`

Comment: so, 'rownumber', as of ur query, is a sql keyword a JW?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26219/discussion-between-jw-and-user1915108)